# MySQL excutes select after where clause

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

This query gives an error unknown column company in where clause. I found that where clause runs first and select runs next. That could be the error here. But i dont know how to correct this in order to get company in result set.

```
SELECT trnsdriverid,
       name,
       (SELECT transcompany.name
        FROM   transcompany,
               transcompdriver
        WHERE  transcompany.trnscompid = transcompdriver.trnscompid) AS 'company',
       address,
       dob,
       license,
       telephone
FROM   transcompdriver
WHERE  ? LIKE 'All'
        OR name LIKE '%"+keyword+"%'
        OR company LIKE '%"+keyword+"%'
        OR trnsdriverid LIKE '%"+keyword+"%'
```

Comment: That's because you are aliasing the result of a nested select as "company" -- that column doesn't actually exist. You can't reference column aliases in where statements. You should rewrite this query to use a JOIN and then do your filtering on the actual `TransCompany.name` column.

Comment: the company column does not have the same amount of rows as the other columns

Comment: @Cory Thnx for your reply. I ll try with join.

Comment: @user2033382: I answered with a query that should work.

Comment: @Cory . Yea its working fine. Thnx lot again. unfortunately cant vote up due to lack of reputations yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference column aliases in where statements. You should rewrite this query to use a JOIN and then do your filtering on the actual TransCompany.name column, for example:

```
select 
     d.trnsDriverID
    ,d.name
    ,c.name as [Company]
    ,d.address
    ,d.dob
    ,d.license
    ,d.telephone 
from 
    TransCompDriver d
join
    TransCompany c
    on
    c.trnscompid = d.trnscompid
where 
    ? = 'All' 
    or 
    d.name like '%" + keyword + "%' 
    or 
    c.name like '%" + keyword + "%' 
    or 
    d.trnsDriverID like '%" + keyword + "%'
```

Also, don't use `LIKE` where a simple equality operator would do. I changed the query above to use `= 'All'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing this using a join rather than a subselect. I would recommend this:

```
SELECT
    d.trnsDriverID,
    d.name,
    c.name AS `company`,
    d.address,
    d.dob,
    d.license,
    d.telephone
FROM
    TransCompDriver AS d
    INNER JOIN TransCompany AS c
        ON d.trnsCompID = c.trnsCompID
WHERE
    ? like 'All'
    OR d.name LIKE '%"+keyword+"%'
    OR `company` LIKE '%"+keyword+"%'
    OR d.trnsDriverID LIKE '%"+keyword+"%'
```

Comment: Thanx lot for your reply. I got similar answer above. both answers working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-query that pulls the column "company" does not have matching number of rows, try the join statement instead

```
select trnsDriverID, name, t1.name AS company, address, dob, license, telephone    
from TransCompDriver JOIN (select trnsDriverID, name, 
(select TransCompany.name from TransCompany LEFT JOIN TransCompDriver   
ON TransCompany.trnsCompID=TransCompDriver.trnsCompID) AS t1   
where ? like 'All' or name like '%"+keyword+"%'   or company like '%"+keyword+"%' 
or trnsDriverID like '%"+keyword+"%'
```